# Battery Broadcast Not Triggered

Tags: java, android

I have written below code in Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jss.battery">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".BatteryReceiver">

            <intent-filter >
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>


            </intent-filter>


        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and below is code for receiver:

```
public class BatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}}
```

But I m not getting any Toast on App launch. and here is code for mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    }
}
```

Is there any error in code? I read many pages with similar issue here but none of solution worked. Also referred https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#DetermineChargeState .At Testing time battery level is 80% +.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY), this broadcast "will be sent after `ACTION_BATTERY_LOW` once the battery has gone back up to an okay state". In your case, the battery is already at 80%, which is well past the low/okay dividing line (which I think is around 15%, but might vary by hardware or OS version).

Comment: Actually I want to run a service on when battery is 100%. for that I can check battery level with  status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL; under receiver, But what to do to trigger receiver then. Is it Action_Battery_Changed in manifest required.

Comment: @Panache: "Actually I want to run a service on when battery is 100%" -- a similar solution is to do your work when the device is charging. You can do that easily via `JobScheduler`. "Is it Action_Battery_Changed in manifest required" -- you cannot receive `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` broadcasts via a receiver registered in the manifest. There is no good way for your app to find out that the battery has reached 100% charge.

Comment: even this   <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/> in manifest does not triggering receiver